# How to get the rect of the last character using Core Text

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-text

I have a `NSAttributedString`, a rect to draw the whole string, I want to get the rect of the last character just like the image below, how to get that using Core Text ?

[image: Get the rect of last char]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Specifically using CoreText, here's a function that should work (with a few comments in the code explaining what's going on):

```
- (CGRect)lastCharacterRectForAttributedString:(NSAttributedString *)attributedString drawingRect:(CGRect)drawingRect
{
    // Start by creating a CTFrameRef using the attributed string and rect.
    CTFrameRef textFrame = NULL;
    CTFramesetterRef framesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString((__bridge CFAttributedStringRef)(attributedString));
    CGPathRef drawingPath = CGPathCreateWithRect(drawingRect, NULL);
    textFrame = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(framesetter, CFRangeMake(0, [attributedString length]), drawingPath, NULL);
    CFRelease(framesetter);
    CFRelease(drawingPath);

    // Line origins can be obtained from the CTFrameRef. Get the final one.
    CGPoint finalLineOrigin;
    CFArrayRef lines = CTFrameGetLines(textFrame);
    if (CFArrayGetCount(lines) == 0) { // Safety check
        CFRelease(textFrame);
        return CGRectNull;
    }
    const CFIndex finalLineIdx = CFArrayGetCount(lines) - 1;
    CTFrameGetLineOrigins(textFrame, CFRangeMake(finalLineIdx, 1), &finalLineOrigin);

    // Get the glyph runs from the final line. Get the last glyph position from the final run.
    CGPoint glyphPosition;
    CFArrayRef runs = CTLineGetGlyphRuns(CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(lines, finalLineIdx));
    if (CFArrayGetCount(runs) == 0) { // Safety check
        CFRelease(textFrame);
        return CGRectNull;
    }
    CTRunRef finalRun = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(runs, CFArrayGetCount(runs) - 1);
    if (CTRunGetGlyphCount(finalRun) == 0) { // Safety check
        CFRelease(textFrame);
        return CGRectNull;
    }
    const CFIndex lastGlyphIdx = CTRunGetGlyphCount(finalRun) - 1;
    CTRunGetPositions(finalRun, CFRangeMake(lastGlyphIdx, 1), &glyphPosition);

    // The bounding box of the glyph itself is extracted from the font.
    CGRect glyphBounds;
    CFDictionaryRef runAttributes = CTRunGetAttributes(finalRun);
    CTFontRef font = CFDictionaryGetValue(runAttributes, NSFontAttributeName);
    CGGlyph glyph;
    CTRunGetGlyphs(finalRun, CFRangeMake(lastGlyphIdx, 1), &glyph);
    CTFontGetBoundingRectsForGlyphs(font, kCTFontDefaultOrientation, &glyph, &glyphBounds, 1);

    // Option 1 - The rect you've drawn in your question isn't tight to the final character; it looks approximately the height of the line. If that's what you're after:
    CGRect lineBounds = CTLineGetBoundsWithOptions(CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(lines, finalLineIdx), 0);
    CGRect desiredRect = CGRectMake(
                                    CGRectGetMinX(drawingRect) + finalLineOrigin.x + glyphPosition.x + CGRectGetMinX(glyphBounds),
                                    CGRectGetMinY(drawingRect) + (CGRectGetHeight(drawingRect) - (finalLineOrigin.y + CGRectGetMaxY(lineBounds))),
                                    CGRectGetWidth(glyphBounds),
                                    CGRectGetHeight(lineBounds)
                                    );
    // Option 2 - If you want a rect that closely bounds the final character, use this:
    /*
    CGRect desiredRect = CGRectMake(
                                    CGRectGetMinX(drawingRect) + finalLineOrigin.x + glyphPosition.x + CGRectGetMinX(glyphBounds),
                                    CGRectGetMinY(drawingRect) + (CGRectGetHeight(drawingRect) - (finalLineOrigin.y + glyphPosition.y + CGRectGetMaxY(glyphBounds))),
                                    CGRectGetWidth(glyphBounds),
                                    CGRectGetHeight(glyphBounds)
                                    );
    */

    CFRelease(textFrame);

    return desiredRect;
}
```

Comment: Hi, @Stefan. I once had a similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21751738/ios-finding-correct-font-size-to-fit-in-a-uilabel-depending-on-its-size) posted up before this one here and I think it is closely related to this one. But instead of just wanting to find the bounding box of the last letter, mine is about finding the sizes of letters on one line  given a certain font and size and space them out (or a `UILabel`) on one line evenly using CoreText. Have a look there, when you got time. Thanks in advance.